# I'm having trouble writing the ADFGVX cipher in python

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography

First of all, if anyone doesn't know how the ADFGVX Cipher works, Here is a video on it:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T0xfKiU9Rr4&t=11s

Assuming you now know how the cipher works, let's look at my problem now:

First, we need to create the Polybius Square. I did this by creating a table:

```
table = 
["THEMAN",
"DLORIB",
"CFGHJK",
"PQRSUV",
"WXYZ12",
"345678"]
```

Next, we need to create a dictionary containing the coordinates:

```
coordinatesdict={}
```

We can create a loop to add the coordinates to the dictionary.

```
for string in table:
    for letter in string:
        coordinatesdict[letter] = [string.index(letter), table.index(string)]
```

When I printed the dictionary, I was expecting this:

```
{T:[0,0],H:[1,0],E:[2,0].....}
#And so on and so forth.
```

What I got instead utterly baffled me:

```
{'T': [0, 0], 'H': [3, 2], 'E': [2, 0], 'M': [3, 0], 'A': [4, 0], 'N': [5, 0], 'D': [0, 1], 'L': [1, 1], 'O': [2, 1], 'R': [2, 3], 'I': [4, 1], 'B': [5, 1], 'C': [0, 2], 'F': [1, 2], 'G': [2, 2], 'J': [4, 2], 'K': [5, 2], 'P': [0, 3], 'Q': [1, 3], 'S': [3, 3], 'U': [4, 3], 'V': [5, 3], 'W': [0, 4], 'X': [1, 4], 'Y': [2, 4], 'Z': [3, 4], '1': [4, 4], '2': [5, 4], '3': [0, 5], '4': [1, 5], '5': [2, 5], '6': [3, 5], '7': [4, 5], '8': [5, 5]}
```

The craziness did not stop there. I debugged the loop and changed it to this:

```
for string in table:
    for letter in string:
        print(letter)
        print([string.index(letter), table.index(string)])
```

Here's what I got after running the loop:

T
[0, 0]
H
[1, 0]
E
[2, 0]
M
[3, 0]
A
[4, 0]
N
[5, 0]
D
[0, 1]
L
[1, 1]
O
[2, 1]
R
[3, 1]
I
[4, 1]
B
[5, 1]
C
[0, 2]
F
[1, 2]
G
[2, 2]
H
[3, 2]
J
[4, 2]
K
[5, 2]
P
[0, 3]
Q
[1, 3]
R
[2, 3]
S
[3, 3]
U
[4, 3]
V
[5, 3]
W
[0, 4]
X
[1, 4]
Y
[2, 4]
Z
[3, 4]
1
[4, 4]
2
[5, 4]
3
[0, 5]
4
[1, 5]
5
[2, 5]
6
[3, 5]
7
[4, 5]
8
[5, 5]

Apparently, When I print them out individually, they are correct, Yet when I plug them into a dictionary, everything goes wrong. Is there an explanation for this? If so, Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Your square is wrong: H in CFGHJK is a repetition, just like R in PQRSUV. And 0 and 9 are missing (26 + 10 = 36, i.e. all letters and digits occur).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I haven't looked at ADFGVX Cipher because I think it is more of a python problem that you are facing here.
The problem here is that **`table`** contains 2 strings that have **`"H"`** in them namely **`"THEMAN"`** and **`"CFGHJK"`**
The way you have written your code it is saying **`coordinatesdict`** to update the value corresponding to key **`"H"`** to a new value whenever it sees one.
Since your code sees a new **`"H"`** at position **`(2,3)`** it updates the value of **`"H"`** to be **`coordinatesdict['H']=[3,2]`** and hence you see your unexpected result.

So in a nutshell you are using a wrong data structure (i.e. `dictionary`) for your problem. You can try [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) or any other data structure for your problem.